# How to initialise an array within a class in C++

Tags: c++, oop, multidimensional-array, attributes, initialization

Here is an idea of my code

```
#include <array>

class B;

class A{
  private : 
    const size_t length;
    
    //3 dimensionnal array called Grid3D (see below)
    
  public : 
    A(size_t length)
    : length(length), Grid3D( std::array<std::array< *B , length>,length>,length>)
    {}
    
    //...
};
```

I don't really know how I'm supposed to do that and I keep having the error `invalid use of non-static data member 'A::length'`. length should not be modified and Grid3D must be an array since its length should not be modified.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: For a `std::array`, the length has to be a constexpr known at compile time.  For a dynamic (at runtime) calculated length, you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: though the error you report is not from the code you posted, it has other errors: https://godbolt.org/z/PrPvrG

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a `std::array`, then you need to make sure the size is known at compile-time. You won't be able to create the grid with a dynamic size (for example, if you won't be able to ask the user what size to make the grid).

The way to do it is by making your `length` a `constexpr` variable and assigning it to a fixed value yourself. Or if you want to leave it up to somebody else to decide what the size should be (but still known at compile-time), then you can accept the size as a template parameter.

```
template<size_t L>
class A {
  Grid Grid3D;
 public:
   A()
    : Grid3D(std::array<std::array<std::array< *B , L>,L>,L>)
    {}
};
```

To use, you simply construct `A<5> myA{};`